How to understand lemma 67.4 in Rogers and William's book?
I am reading the book Diffusions, Markov process, and Martingales (volume 1) by L. Rogers and D. William.
In page 172, Lemma (67.4), the authors state that:

The usual augmentation of $(\Omega,\mathcal{G},P,\mathcal{G}_t)$ is obtained by making $\mathcal{F}$ the $P$-completion of $\mathcal{G}$, and, with $\mathcal{N}$ denoting the collection of $P$-null sets in $\mathcal{F}$, setting
$$\mathcal{F}_t=\cap_{u>t}\sigma(\mathcal{G}_u,\mathcal{N})=\sigma(\mathcal{G}_{t+},\mathcal{N}).$$
If $t\geq 0$ and $F\in \mathcal{F}_t$, then there exists $G$ in $\mathcal{G}_{t+}$ such that
$$F\Delta G:=(F\backslash G) \cup (G\backslash F)\in \mathcal{N}.$$

What does the second sentence mean?
Is it just a result of $\mathcal{F}_t=\sigma(\mathcal{G}_{t+},\mathcal{N})$? In other word, do we have the following result?
$$\mathcal{F}=\sigma(\mathcal{G},\mathcal{N}) \Leftrightarrow \forall F\in\mathcal{F}, \exists G\in\mathcal{G}, s.t. F\Delta G\in\mathcal{N}$$

The answer is yes.
Claim. Suppose $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P)$ it our probability space. Let $\mathcal{G}$ a sigma-algebra and let $\mathcal{N}$ the collection of $P$-null sets. Define the augmented sigma-algebra as $\mathcal{G}^{aug}:=\sigma(\mathcal{G},\mathcal{N})$ and define
$$\mathcal{F}:=\{F\subseteq\Omega:\exists G\in\mathcal{G} \,\, \text{such that} \,\, F\Delta G\in \mathcal{N}\}$$
Then, we have $\mathcal{G}^{aug}=\mathcal{F}$.
Proof.
Clearly, $\mathcal{F}$ is a sigma-algebra. First, we have $\emptyset \in \mathcal{F}$. Second, $F\in\mathcal{F}$ implies there exists a $G\in\mathcal{G}$ with $F^c\Delta G^c = F\Delta G\in \mathcal{N}$, so $F^c\in\mathcal{F}$. Finally, for any sequence $\{F_n\}_n\in\mathcal{F}$, we have a companian sequence $\{G_n\}_n\in\mathcal{G}$ such that
$$(\cup_n F_n)\Delta(\cup_n G_n)\subseteq \cup_n (F_n\Delta G_n)\in\mathcal{N}$$
which yields $\cup_n F_n \in\mathcal{F}$.
To explain, note that LHS=$(\cup_n F_n \backslash \cup_n G_n) \cup (\cup_n G_n \backslash \cup_n F_n)$ and RHS=$(\cup_n F_n \backslash G_n)\cup(\cup_n G_n \backslash F_n)$. Since $\cup_n F_n \backslash \cup_n G_n \subseteq \cup_n F_n \backslash G_n$, we have LHS$\subseteq$RHS.
$\hspace{5cm}$
Further, note that $F\Delta G=N \Leftrightarrow F=G\Delta N$, so we have
$$\mathcal{F}=\{F\subseteq \Omega:\exists G \in \mathcal{G}, N\in \mathcal{N} \,\, \text{such that} \,\, F=G\Delta N\}$$
which means each element of $\mathcal{F}$ is in $\mathcal{G}^{aug}$ and hence $\mathcal{F}\subseteq \mathcal{G}^{aug}$.
Moreover, $\mathcal{F}$ contains both $\mathcal{G}$ and $\mathcal{N}$, and since it is a sigma-algebra, $\mathcal{G}^{aug}\subseteq \mathcal{F}$ ($\mathcal{G}^{aug}$ is the smallest sigma-algebra containing $\mathcal{G}$ and $\mathcal{N}$).
Together, these means $\mathcal{F} = \mathcal{G}^{aug}$, which concludes the proof.
